# How do I mutate value of a tensor in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, dplyr, tensorflow.js

How do I mutate value of a tensor in Tensorflow.js? For example if I have a tensor created like this:

`const a = tf.tensor1d([1,2,3,4])`

How do I change the value of the third element of the tensor? I know that tensors are immutable and variables are mutable.

Doing this: `const a = tf.variable(tf.tensor1d([1,2,3,4]))` doesn't seem to solve the problem. I cannot do:

`const a = a[0].assign(5)`

I am able to do this in **python tensorflow** like this:

`a = tf.Variable([1,2,3,4])
a = a[0].assign(100)
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_iniliazer())
   print sess.run(a)`

This outputs `[100, 2,3,4]`

Answer (score 5):

Does [`tf.buffer`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#buffer) work for you?

```
// Create a buffer and set values at particular indices.
const a = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const buffer = tf.buffer(a.shape, a.dtype, a.dataSync());
buffer.set(5, 0);
const b = buffer.toTensor();
// Convert the buffer back to a tensor.
b.print();
```

---

```
Tensor
    [5, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This works thanks. How do i set the value of multiple indices at the same time

Comment: I suspect you will need to use a for loop for this for now.  There isn't a bulk edit operation.  You can also pull the data from your tensor into an array, edit the array, and then create a new tensor.  Keep in mind that back-propagation won't work through this escape hatch.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this using `mulStrict` and `addStrict` which do element-wise multiplication and addition.

```js
const a = tf.tensor1d([1,2,3,4]);
tf.mulStrict(a, tf.tensor1d([0,1,1,1]))
  .addStrict(tf.tensor1d([100, 0, 0, 0]);
```

This was based on asnwer 
[here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/180#issuecomment-380818111)