# Removing specific values from tensor.. using conditional

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am trying to figure out how to remove specific values in a tensor created by tensorflow js..

if the element in the tensor is > than a specific value.. how do i remove the value or reduce it to zero.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mutate value of a tensor in Tensorflow.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49802499/how-do-i-mutate-value-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow-js)

Comment: no.. it doesnt provide a conditional. also doesn't maintaining the calculation in numpy or tensor alot quicker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.